# Prove if $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ −1, 0 \}$, $\frac{m + 1}{n+1}$>$\frac{m}{n}$

Tags: provability

How to prove if $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ −1, 0 \}$ then $\frac{m + 1}{n+1} > \frac{m}{n}$ ?

I started by realizing $n \subset m$ and if we choose $x \in n$ it also means that $x \in m$. I don't know if I need to do that in order to prove the argument though and how to go on with it.

Comment: n and m are not sets, to begin with

Comment: The inequality fails for $m=2,\;n = 1$. My guess is that you were asked to prove _or_ disprove the claim. If so, one counterexample (such the one I just gave) suffices for a disproof.

Answer (score 1):

For $m=n$ it's wrong.

$$\frac{m + 1}{n+1}-\frac{m}{n}=\frac{n-m}{n(n+1)}>0$$
for $n>m$.